# Getting Current Date inside a C++ process running 24*7

Tags: c++, date, c++11

I have a backend process running 24*7 mostly built using C++ and I need to validate if an input date (in format YYYYMMDD) belongs in a set of next 5 business days. The input date is not a clear indicator of the current date so I am using the following function to get the current date and then calculating the next 5 business days from it.

```
const std::string& CurrentDateStr() {
        static const std::string sDate = []() {
            time_t currTime = time(NULL);
            struct tm timeinfo;
            localtime_r(&currTime, &timeinfo);
            char buffer[16]="";
            strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y%m%d", &timeinfo);
            return std::string(buffer);
        } ();
        return sDate;
    }
```

This function returns me the correct current date if the process was started today but if the process continues running till tomorrow then it will return me yesterday's date as current date due to which calculation of next 5 business days from current date goes for a toss.

Is this expected ? Is there some workaround for it or is there a better way to implement the requirement using standard C++

Comment: You're going to a lot of trouble in that code to make sure the date returned is always the same. If that's not what you want why make is so?

Comment: Also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: the function you want to use if you receive a YYYYMMDD string is strptime from which you can extract a `struct tm`. From that you can obtain a `time_t` and you compare that with current `time_t` (obtained via time(NULL)) + 5 /*days*/ * 24 /*hours*/ * 60 /* mins */ * 60 /* seconds */

Comment: The "workaround" is to not just get the date the first time the function is called. (Also, if you're going to use the date for further calculations, strings are no good - use a proper date type.)

Comment: @Mat I want the function to return the current date irrespective of it's invocation on any of the days during which the process keeps running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the static variable. You should read up on that, because you're going to encounter it a lot. This is what the comments were trying to get you to do. You can fix your issue by just removing it:

```cpp
const std::string& CurrentDateStr() {
            time_t currTime = time(NULL);
            struct tm timeinfo;
            localtime_r(&currTime, &timeinfo);
            char buffer[16]="";
            strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y%m%d", &timeinfo);
            return std::string(buffer);
    }
```

For a more modern solution, as suggested in the comments as well, read up on chrono. Especially system_clock::now().

Answer (score -1):

one way to do it using chrono:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        theTime currentTime = time(nullptr);
        tm* date = gmtime(&currentTime);
        // Print the date and time
        std::cout << "Current date and time: " << date->theDay << "/" << date->theMon + 1 << "/" << date->theYear + 1900;
        std::cout << " " << date->theHour << ":" << date->theMmin << ":" << date->theSec << std::endl;
        // Wait for 1 minute
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1));
    }
}
```

**OR** Use the sleep method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        time_t currentTime = time(nullptr);
        tm* date = gmtime(&currentTime);
        std::cout << "Current date and time: " << date->tm_mday << "/" << date->tm_mon + 1 << "/" << date->tm_year + 1900;
        std::cout << " " << date->tm_hour << ":" << date->tm_min << std::endl;
        // Wait for 1 minute (60 seconds)
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted, because it's not really what the asker wants I think. This creates a blocking loop, updating the time every minute. The op is just asking to make their function always return the current date.

Comment: Also, I've just realized, your chrono suggestion doesn't actually use chrono except for the sleep. Copy-paste error?